# Sigma-algebra defined on Ω

Tags: probability-theory

How can I prove that if $\mathcal A$ is a sigma-algebra defined on $Ω$, then the class $\mathcal A^c = \{A^c: A∈\mathcal A\}$  is a sigma-algebra defined on $Ω$? I tried through the properties of a sigma algebra and the theorems derived from it, but I'm not convinced

Comment: You must have a typo somewhere.  There is no way that the complement of a sigma algebra is going to have any nice structure at all.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith I think OP means his = sign as standing for a definition, not a usual complement. I agree a bit sloppy but... Do you have a different objection to OP question if the initial $\mathcal{A}^c \ =$ is dropped?

Comment: As it is, I don't understand what question the OP meant to ask.  But if he/she fixes the typo, I think then I will understand.

Comment: Also, they have an $\mathcal A^c$ inside the set.  So its definition is circular.

Comment: @coffeemath I posted an answer based on your interpretation. I hope that is the correct interpretation.

Comment: I've fixed my typo. Excuse me

Answer (score 1):

Please see the second paragraph below for the revised version of the question.

If your class consists of complements of sets which are not in $\mathcal A$ the result is false.  Consider the Borel sigma algebra of the real line. Let $A$ be a subset of $(0,1)$ which is not  Borel set and $B$ be a subset of $(1,2)$ which is not  Borel set. Then your class contains $A^{c}$ and $B^{c}$ but it does not contain the union of these two sets since $A \cap B=\emptyset $ is a Borel set.

On the other hand is you are considering the class of all sets $A^{c}$ such that $A \in \mathcal A$ then this new class is same as $\mathcal A$ itself, so it  is a sigma algebra.

Comment: I've fixed my typo. Excuse me

Comment: They are using $\overline {A}, A^{c}$ and $A'$ and I don't know what these symbols meas. Do you  think $\overline {A}$ is the complement of $A$? @Khazanie

Comment: Yes, is the complement

Comment: What difference do you find between $\mathcal A^{c}$ and $\mathcal A$? They are the same by definition of  a sigma algebra. @Khazanie

Comment: I dont understand that :(

Comment: If $A \in \mathcal A$ then $A^{c} \in \mathcal A$ which means $A \in \mathcal A^{c}$. the converse follows from the fact that $A=(A^{c})^{c}$.  So $\mathcal A^{c}=\mathcal A$ @Khazanie